# Use google image charts to export image to excel?

Tags: image, grails, charts

I am building a web application with grails and using the jxl API to generate an excel file to allow formatting.  I would like to generate a chart using data in my application to include with the excel file.

The only source I have found to create a static image that could be saved and then inserted into the excel file is the deprecated Google image charts API to build a URL string to retrieve the corresponding chart.

1. Should I be concerned about doing this with the deprecated google image charts, or should I be fine, given that I am only using the pie chart type?
2. Should I be going about this entirely different?  Using the browser to save the image could be problematic because the app needs to support ie. 7-9.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would worry that Google would just remove the service after 2015; it might not matter that it's just a simple pie chart if the remove the service completely.  I don't know the likelihood of that happening, but could be a concern.

You could use the [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) API to generate the chart as a png and the use jxl to insert it into the spreadseet using `sheet.addImage()`.

There is an example of creating the chart using Grails [here](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/03/31/generating-dyanmic-charts-in-grails/)

Comment: Thanks.  The JFreeChart works well and fit the needs of my project.